# How to parameterized Hibernate Constraint message to contain field name?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have the following annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = IdValidator.class)
public @interface Id {
  String message() default "{Id field cannot be null}";
}
```

that I'm using on my class

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    String firstName;
    @Id
    String lastName;
}
```

When I call

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<FakePerson>> violations = validator.validate(person);
```

I want a `ConstrainstViolation` to have a message that says **"firstName cannot be null"**. How can I do that?

Is there a way to create the messages associate with the path inside the `ConstraintValidator`?

```
public class IdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Id, Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)   
  {
     //Ideally I can build the messages associate with the property here with ConstraintValidatorContext
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

The first would be to add a new attribute to your annotation, shown below is `label`.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PKFieldValidator.class)
public @interface Id {
  String message() default "{Id field cannot be null}";
  String label();
}
```

Then in the class, you'd use

```
@Id(label="firstName")
private String firstName;
@Id(label="lastName")
private String lastName;
```

Then simply make your message be something like

```
Id.message={label} is required.
```

But the problem with that approach is that you're dropping in bean field names into translations that could be in other languages.  How much sense does `Se requiere el firstName` make in Spanish?

My preferred suggestion is to actually keep bean validation messages generic.  Things such as `Field is required` or `Must be greater than 0` seem very reasonable to me and allows for reuse.

For situations where you need to associate these violation messages with the properties, simply iterate the violations, get the `propertyPath` and print the path plus the message to your logs or whatnot.

From web frameworks, I prefer to do precisely that, iterate the constraint violations, adding them to a `Map<String,String>` where the key is the `propertyPath` and the value is the violation message.  Then in the UI, I associate the message next to each of the field's input controls, keeping things clean and concise all the while easy for the user to understand and read.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question but I was hoping there's a way to get the `propertyPath` in the `ConstraintValidator.isValid()` so the message can be defined in one place. If we generate the messages after getting `Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations` then we have to do that everything.

Comment: Encapsulate the exception handling logic to a separate class and invoke that.  I've done that in numerous cases where we need to do exception class translations (internal exceptions to JPA exceptions) or situations where controller exception handling needed to be centralized.  You could also use AspectJ if you wanted as a build post compile step.